# Ubuntu 16.04 message of the day not updating number of package updates.

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

For the last month my amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04 has had the same message of the day (motd):

> 30 packages can be updated.
>
> 10 updates are security updates.

I have run the suggested commands:

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

After rebooting the instance the motd does not change. There are no packages to update, it is only the motd not updating.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by changing the shebang in the apt-check script from:

> sudo vi /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check
>
> #!/usr/bin/python3

to

> #!/usr/bin/python3.5

python3 was calling a python interpreter without the module apt_pkg installed. After changing it back to the default python3.5 the motd is updating properly.

If anyone else has a similar problem in the future you can run this command to manually check if there are packages available to update:

> python3.5 /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable

or

> sudo  /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available

Answer (score 0):

The following commands fixed my issue:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Notice that my commands **do not** contain `-get`. As far as I can tell, `apt` and `apt-get` are two different things. It looks like the Message Of The Day (MOTD) on my installation was referring to `apt`.